# Does ProGuard work in reverse mode?

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

It seems that by default ProGuard obfuscates everything and you have to add `keep` statements if you want something to exclude. Can it work in reverse mode? I want ProGuard to obfuscate only specific files and leave everything else untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this adding the following rule:

```
-keep class !your.class.to.obfuscate,
            !your.other.class.to.obfuscate,
            !....,
            ** { *; }
```

This will keep everything (classes,methods,fields) apart from the classes that you excluded. The excluded classes will be obfuscated.